# R function to convert values within 3 standard deviations of mean to binary

Tags: r, standard-deviation

I'm new to R, and I've been tasked to create a function to compare and translate the data mined from a simulated network to analyse user patterns.

The R app is supposed to calculate the sum of each protocol used, the mean of the sum and the standard deviation of the sum. The function is currently:

```
> total[total == 0] <- NA
res2 <- do.call(`data.frame`,
                aggregate(values~ind, stack(total), 
                          FUN=function(x) c(Total=sum(x, na.rm=FALSE), Mean=mean(x) SD=sd(x)))
```

And to use another function to translate the value to 1 if the user's protocol count is within "Mean - 3sd < count < Mean + 3sd"

```
> nm1 <- setdiff(colnames(total), "row.names")
output[,nm1] <-(res2$Mean-3SD[col(total[,nm1])] >total[,nm1] >res2$Mean-3SD[col(total[,nm1])])+0
```

Is this the correct method for comparison?

Thanks

**Edit:**

While running the code, it shows:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "output[,nm1] <-(res2$Mean-3SD"
```

Comment: `output` is not defined.  Please provide a reproducible example.  If you want to add new column to the original dataset based on the summarised values, `aggregate` may not be the best tool.  Use `ave` or you could do this easily with `dplyr` or `data.table`

Comment: It should be `3 * SD...`. A reproducible example would be wonderful, though.

Comment: The results of the comparison will be written into a new table. :/

Answer (score 1):

R doesn't understand double inequalities like `A < B < C` as `<` and its family are binary operators. Hence, the above should be translated to `A < B & B < C` to be syntactically valid.

Now, you didn't provide a reproducible example, but in your case the line

```
output[,nm1] <- (res2$Mean-3SD[col(total[,nm1])] > total[,nm1] > res2$Mean-3SD[col(total[,nm1])])+0
```

should be something like

```
output[,nm1] <- 
 (res2$Mean - 3*SD[col(total[,nm1])] > total[,nm1] & 
    total[,nm1] > res2$Mean - 3*SD[col(total[,nm1])]) + 0
```

As far as I can tell. Does that help?

Edit: Also, as said in the comment by Roman Luštrik you should also remember explicit multiplication `*`.